# App review process - Adding a video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube-api

I have integrated a youtube video to my application. I have included a Movie trailer as a sample video. Now i am going to submit the app for apple to review. I need to know if they'll reject the app because the app contains a movie trailer ?

Comment: Do you have copyright to the video you're distributing?

Comment: Don't think that this could be a problem as long as you own the video. I remember that ... Train ... the game by Matt Rix with the trains, you hopefully know what game I mean, included a YouTube video in which he spoke about the new features. `Edit:` The name is Trainyard. :)

Comment: Well, i don't own the video. Is it a must to include something that i own ?

Comment: Yes, you need to hold a license to use to **everything** in your app. Images, custom fonts, video, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Apple may very well reject the app if you do not own the video. You are violating someones copyright if you use that video. If (thats a big if) this app did get approved you could be held liable for placing this content on your app. By submitting an app you are agreeing to take 100% responsibility for your app, so they come after you and not apple. You need to either obtain written permission from the owner of the video, or remove the video.

Play it safe and either create a little video your self, or find a video that is not copyrighted.

Answer (score 2):

As others people have mentionned, you *should* have legal rights to the video (and anything else) you're playing.

I simply wanted to add that, upon trying to play the video, the app should fail gracefully if it has no Internet connection (i.e. it shouldn't crash the app)... as that might be cause for rejection.

Comment: Not just the video, either. Everything in the app needs to be his or legitimately licensed.

Comment: When there is no internet, the go to the youtube video but, the loading message keeps on appearing. It doesn't crash but the user is not notified if there is no internet. (This hapence only for the youtube video, i check for no internet in other parts of the code)

Answer (score 1):

As we all know how restrict Apple is in it's rules, regulations and copyrights. You should not violate somebody else's copyright. Apple may reject your application because of that. You should own everything about your app(like images, sounds, movie files etc.).

**Solution** :- Create a short movie and use that or you can use any open-source movie which is licensed as anyone can use it(Which is not copyright by someone else).